# Tables within tables Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table

I'm trying to get Obama's 2009 speech from this website:

http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/ws/index.php?pid=85753

And it looks like there is multiple tables within tables, and I can't seem to navigate through it with beautifulsoup to get the text of his speech.

Any ideas?

Comment: i just ask for checking - is there only two `table`s?

Comment: When i look through the site I see a crap ton way more then 2.

Comment: i mean table tags. it just shows two `<table>` tags.

Comment: Im still fairly new at webscraping but when I look at the website I see multiple <table> tags, am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Search for the `class="displaytext"` and get the parent `<td>`, then iterate through the '`<p>`' tags in it.

Comment: when I do just    soup.find(class_='displaytext') it shows []

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
the_soup.select('span.displaytext')[0].text
```